How to resolve "None of the provided servers are under the root origin" error when specifying port in OpenAI Custom GPT API schema?
I'm working with OpenAI's Custom GPT and trying to integrate it with my API using an OpenAPI specification. My API is hosted on a server that requires a specific port (e.g., 9443), and I've specified this port in the servers section of my OpenAPI schema:
servers:
  - url: https://prod.vedicastrologer.ai:9443

However, when I attempt to create an action in Custom GPT, I encounter an error saying:
None of the provided servers are under the root origin prod.vedicastrologer.ai, so the server URL is not under the root origin, and it is being ignored.

It seems that Custom GPT expects the base URL (root origin) to match exactly with the root origin it has been configured with, but the inclusion of the port seems to be causing a mismatch.
My questions are:

How can I correctly configure my OpenAPI schema to include the
required port without encountering this root origin mismatch error?
Is there a way to allow Custom GPT to accept a port in the server
URL, or do I need to set up my API differently?
Are there any best practices for dealing with API endpoints that
require specific ports when integrating with OpenAI's Custom GPT?

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!
